# How to show $x\in(0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Problem is to show $(0,1]$ is subset of $\cup [\frac{1}{n},1]$.

What I have so far is:

Let $x$ be in $(0,1]$. And I want to show $x\in[\frac{1}{n}, 1]$

Comment: Take $n >\frac1  x$.

Comment: Okay, and 1/x cannot be zero right? because 0 does not include in the interval...

Answer (score 0):

For each given $x$, try to find a $n$ such that $x$ is in the interval $[1/n,1]$.

Can you find a $n$ for **every** $x$? Then you have proven your theorem.

Comment: I do not get it...

Answer (score 0):

Take $x\in (0,1)$. There exists $n>0$ such that $0<1/n<x$ ( because the sequence $(1/n$ goes to 0, as $n\to\infty$). Then $x$ is in $[1/n,1]$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank You